# Non-assignable error in directive when using ternary operator

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I have a directive that has an isolate scope with an `action` property. When using a ternary operator in the view, I'm getting `Expression 'ctrl.someBoolean ? 'Some Text' : 'Different Text'' used with directive 'myDirective' is non-assignable!`

**Usages**

```
 <my-directive name='My Name' action="ctrl.someBoolean ? 'Some Text' : 'Different Text'">

 <my-directive name='My Name 2' action="'Some Static Text'">
```

**Directive**

```
 angular.module('example')
  .directive('myDirective', [
    function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: 'myDirective.html',
        scope: {
          name: '@',
          action: '=?'
        },
        require: ['myDirective', 'form'],
        controller: 'MyDirectiveCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        bindToController: true
      };
    }]);
```

**Directive Controller**

```
angular.module('example')
  .controller('MyDirectiveCtrl', ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs',
    function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      var vm = this;

      vm.action = angular.isDefined($attrs.action) ? $attrs.action : 'Default Action';
    }
  ])
```

Comment: Not enough info. How do you use directive in HTML?

Comment: Added example usages

Answer (score 2):

From the way you are using directive, it is better not to use two-way binding. What you need is simple one-way attribute interpolation, i.e. directive usage should be:

```
<my-directive name='My Name' action="{{ ctrl.someBoolean ? 'Some Text' : 'Different Text' }}"></my-directive>
```

and directive scope configuration

```
scope: {
    name: '@',
    action: '@?'
},
```

Why Angular throws an error if you use two-way binding with ternary expression? It is easy to understand if you think about what *two-way binding* means. Primary purpose of it is to allow directive scope modify original outer scope value. However, it is not possible to assign new value to expression like `ctrl.someBoolean ? 'Some Text' : 'Different Text'`. Hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use this in this place. Try:

```
var vm = {};
vm.action = angular.isDefined($attrs.action) ? $attrs.action : 'Default Action';
```